# Not able to Upload multiple file with multipart-form data content type using swagger yaml openapi 3.0. please suggest

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, openapi, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

I am using openapi 3.0 to generate application rest API using swagger.yaml file. While executing swagger yaml with maven build, it is generating API but with no request body and content type.
How we can upload multiple file with the help of swagger yaml openapi 3.0. Also please suggest **request body and response body** for swagger yaml so it can help me to generate proper Rest API.

Comment: Can you post your yaml please?